# Django/sqlite3 "OperationalError: no such table" on threaded operation

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite, python-multithreading

By everything I read in the docs, both Django and py-sqlite3 should be fine with threaded access. (Right?) But this code snippet fails for me. The operations in the main thread work, but not in the thread(s) I create.  There I get:

> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\sq
>   lite3\base.py", line 323, in execute
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>
> **OperationalError: no such table**: thrtest_mymodel

What's the problem?

How do I go about tracking down exactly what's happening to patch Django or whatever's necessary to fix it? The point of failure in Django is pretty indimidating. I can't tell how to see what tables it DOES see, or what differences to look for between main and other threads.

```
from django.db import models

# Super-simple model
class MyModel(models.Model):
    message       = models.CharField('Message', max_length=200, blank=True)

#Test
from django.test import TestCase

import time
import threading
import random


done = threading.Event()
nThreads = 1


def InsertRec(msg):
    rec = MyModel.objects.create(message=msg)
    rec.save()


def InsertThread():
    try:
        msgNum = 1
        thrName = threading.currentThread().name
        print 'Starting %s' % thrName
        while not done.wait(random.random() * 0.1):
            msgNum += 1
            msg = '%s: %d' % (thrName, msgNum)
            print msg
            InsertRec(msg)
    finally:
        done.set()
    pass


class ThreadTestRun(TestCase):

    def testRunIt(self):
        nThisThread = 10
        msgSet = set()
        for x in xrange(nThisThread):
            msg = 'Some message %d' % x
            InsertRec(msg) # From main thread: works!
            msgSet.add(msg)
        self.assertEqual(MyModel.objects.count(), nThisThread)
        # We use sets because .all() doesn't preserve the original order.
        self.assertEqual(msgSet, set([r.message for r in MyModel.objects.all()]))
        thrSet = set()
        for thrNum in xrange(nThreads):
            t = threading.Thread(name='Thread %d' % thrNum, target=InsertThread)
            t.start()
            thrSet.add(t)

        done.wait(10.)
        done.set()
        for t in thrSet:
            t.join()
```

*Update*: Here is DATABASES from settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:', # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'TEST_NAME' : ':memory:',
    },
}
```

*Update*: With respect to Django's ticket #12118, I get the same symptoms using `':memory:'` or a disk file (for `TEST_NAME`).

Django 1.9, Python 2.7.11. (Same symptoms in Django 1.6.)

Comment: What do your DATABASES settings look like?

Comment: This seems related, although it seems to be fixed in 1.8.x and 1.9.x. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12118

Answer (score 5):

Change your `DATABASES` like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
        'TEST' : 
            {
                'NAME': 'test_db',
            }
    },
}
```

This will force django to create a real sqlite db on the disk, instead of creating it in memory.

Also be sure to inherit your test cases related to threading from `django.test.testcases.TransactionTestCase`. If you don't do so, the threads won't see database changes made from another threads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is one of the configurations I tried (last update above--older django version uses 'TEST_NAME' vs. 'TEST':{'NAME': ...}).  Tests that just check something and finish all work fine, but my multithreaded test that runs quite a while just suddenly in the middle gives notification that the database has changed, and all the tables are gone. Like the database automatically rolled back.

Comment: strange :/ as a last option you can say django to keep the database after the test with `--keepdb` key.

Comment: I get a new exception after adding this: "database is locked"